# Avoiding nulls in LastOrDefault

Tags: c#

I was wondering how can I specify a default value of `DateTime.MinValue` in the code below for when the `ItemList` is empty (i.e avoid null reference exceptions)

```
List<MyFoo> list = GetList();
foreach (MyFoo foo in list.OrderBy(x =>x.ItemList.LastOrDefault().Received))
   Console.WriteLine(foo);

public class MyFoo
{        
    public List<Item> ItemList { get; set; }
    public MyFoo()
    {
        ItemList = new List<Item>();            
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public DateTime Received { get; set; }              
}
```

I know that if Item was a struct (i.e. a Data Type) this code would work fine, but is there any way to produce similar behavior with a reference type?

Comment: In C# 6 or above, you could use expression `?.` to avoid processing `.Received` when `LastOrDefault()` is `null`

Comment: @Servy not a duplicate. How is *sorting* going to be affected by that null?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's asking how to use a non-null default value when getting a singular item out of a possibly empty list.  Why they want to do that is irrelevant to either question.

Comment: @cesar21 how do you want to sort items that have an empty `ItemList`? Should they appear first or last ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The question specifies that they should use `DateTime.MinValue` as the value of the projection when the list has no item.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But hey, re-answering duplicate questions over and over again gets you more rep than just leaving them closed as duplicates that answer the question, and apparently rep is all that matters...

Comment: Thank you guys. This was very educational. Time to refactor some code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [null-conditional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) `?.` operator to avoid null reference exceptions if `ItemList` is empty and return `null`. After that, you can use the [null-coalescing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator `??` to replace the null value with a default value.

If you want records with an empty `Received` value to appear first, the default should be `DateTime.MinValue`, eg:

```
list.OrderBy(x =>x.ItemList.LastOrDefault()?.Received ?? DateTime.MinValue)
```

or `DateTime.MaxValue` to have them appear last:

```
list.OrderBy(x =>x.ItemList.LastOrDefault()?.Received ?? DateTime.MaxValue)
```

Comment: Perhaps what you mean is `?.` instead of `.?`

Answer (score 2):

Use this syntax:

```
foreach (MyFoo foo in list.OrderBy(x =>x.ItemList.LastOrDefault()?.Received ?? DateTime.MinValue))
   Console.WriteLine(foo);
```

So your 'OrderBy' operator will use the `DateTime.MinValue` value if the list is null.

See: [?? Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) and [?. Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my comment, in C# 6 and above, you could use `null-conditional` expression to avoid processing `.Received` when `LastOrDefault()` is `null`. Also, you could combine it with `null-coalescing` operator `??` to specify the minimum value `DateTime.MinValue` when the `LastOrDefault()` is `null` as follow:

```
foreach (MyFoo foo in list.OrderBy(x =>x.ItemList.LastOrDefault()?.Received ?? DateTime.MinValue))
   Console.WriteLine(foo);
```

Here are references from MSDN: 
null-conditional expression: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx
null-coalescing operator: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx